How to eliminate large gap between dynamically rendered objects in R Shiny?
In the below example code, the size of the 4 rendered plots changes as the user expands or contracts the window as desired. The size changes dynamically per the HTML in the code below. However, how do I eliminate the large gap between the rendered plots and the data table underneath the plots when first invoking the App? As shown in the image below. Oddly, that large gap disappears after the user adjusts the size of the window, whether the window is expanded or contracted. Even if the size adjustment is slight, the gap disappears.
Please help me eliminate that large gap when first rendering the App. My HTML and CSS skills are weak.

Example code:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(gridExtra)  

data <- data.frame(X = 1:100,Original = runif(100),Fitted = runif(100))

plotFun <- function(data, title) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Original)) +
    geom_point(color = "blue", size = 2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Fitted), color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    ggtitle(title) +
    theme_minimal()
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(HTML("
    $(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
      function adjustPlotSize() {
        var width = $('#plotContainer').width();
        $('#plotContainer').height(width);
      }
      $(window).resize(adjustPlotSize);
      adjustPlotSize();
    });
  ")),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plotContainer", width = "100%"), 
    DTOutput("dataTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plotContainer <- renderPlot({
    p1 <- plotFun(data, "Plot 1")
    p2 <- plotFun(data, "Plot 2")
    p3 <- plotFun(data, "Plot 3")
    p4 <- plotFun(data, "Plot 4")
    grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
  }, res = 96)
  
  output$dataTable <- renderDT({datatable(data)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Does this answer your question? Neatly display images of different sizes sequentially in the same UI element

Maybe there's a cleaner solution out there, but something that works for now is triggering a resize event using HTML after the page has fully loaded:
 tags$script(HTML("
    $(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
      function adjustPlotSize() {
        var width = $('#plotContainer').width();
        $('#plotContainer').height(width);
      }
      // Schedule adjustPlotSize to execute after the page has loaded
      $(window).resize(adjustPlotSize); // Bind to resize event
      setTimeout(function() {
        adjustPlotSize(); // Adjust immediately on load
        $(window).trigger('resize'); // Trigger resize to adjust layout
      }); 
    });
  ")),

